# Template of multiple abstract classes

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class

There are many questions about template specialization with abstract classes, still I couldn't find something that helped me solve my problem.

First of all, let's say that we have three abstract classes: `A`, `B` and `C`. Both `B` and `C` are derived from `A`:

```cpp
class A {
    virtual void do_something();
};

class B : public A {
    virtual void do_something_else();
};

class C : public A {
    virtual void do_something_different();
};
```

Now, let's say that I have a templated class that should take as template parameters classes derived from `A`. I can implement this constraint using C++11 `std::is_base_of`. This class has a method `execute`. What I want to accomplish is this: is the template parameter is also derived from `B`, this method should have only one parameter, if it's derived from `C`, the method should have two parameters.

How do I do that? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

C++20 way:

```
#include <concepts>
template<typename ty>
struct foo{ 
    return_type bar() requires std::drived_from<ty,A>;
    return_type bar(arg_type1) requires std::drived_from<ty,B>;
    return_type bar(arg_type1,arg_type2) requires std::drived_from<ty,C>;
};
```

Comment: In the first snippet, the functions need to be templated (with the condition depending on func's own template params). There are some typos in both snippets, and I believe in both snippets the conditions need to be non-overlapping.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, could you show me how it should have been written?

Comment: Something like `template <typename T = ty> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, ty> && std::is_base_of_v<A, T>, return_type>`, etc. The typos should be obvious, and so is writing non-overlapping conditions.

Comment: I need to deal with old code later. Thank everyone for constructive hints. When you get used to _t and _v, such typos happen. I will comeback sometime later. I must improve this answer.